# Point of strength versus strength feat

Tags: feats, ability-scores, dnd-next-playtest

Why would anyone take a point of Strength when they'd get an ability score increase, if taking the Athlete feat instead does that and more?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you choose an ability score increase, you can get either +2 to a single ability score or  +1 to two different ability scores. Feats like Athlete and Loremaster allow you to get +1 to a particular ability score (fixed for each feat) and trade the other for a feat-specific benefit.

Comment: Ah. I didn't notice that the ability score increase gave two points instead of one.